# Prove that the determinant of polynomials is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, determinant

Prove that this determinant is zero (this matrix is $n\times n$):
$$\begin{vmatrix}
f_1(a_1) & f_1(a_2) & \cdots & f_1(a_n) \\
f_2(a_1) & f_2(a_2) & \cdots & f_2(a_n) \\
\vdots   & \vdots   & \ddots & \vdots_\strut  \\
f_n(a_1) & f_n(a_2) & \cdots & f_n(a_n)
\end{vmatrix}$$
Every $f_i$ is a polynomial of degree $n-2$ maximum.

I had an idea that, because there are $n$ polynomials and the degree of each one is at most $n-2$, the lines of the matrix must be linearly dependent and therefore the determinant is $0$? I don't know how to write a formal and clear solution to this, I think my idea is pretty rough and need to be explained clearly.. can anyone help me please?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the matrix $A$ where the entry $a_{ij}$ is the coefficient of $x^{j-1}$ in the polynomial $f_i$.

What is the maximal rank of this $n \times (n-1)$ matrix $A$?

What does this tell you about the linear independence of the rows?

What does this tell you about the linear independence of the polynomials?